# XAMPP - Access to the requested object is only available from the local network

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

When I try to access an phpMyAdmin of xampp in another pc using ip address I get this error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> New XAMPP security concept:
>
> Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.
>
> This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

I was searching for the solution and found a bunch of suggestions like modifying `httpd-xampp.conf` file.

1) Option was to modify `<LocationMatch>` block like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

The problem is that my `httpd-xampp.conf` file does not contain such a block, but if I try to add it to the end of the file I still get the same error.

2) Option was to modify `<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">` as following:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Or

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Or

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

This didn't solve the problem either. Still getting same error.

**P.S. I am restarting Apache after each change!**

Could someone see what I could be missing?

Comment: Dont use both Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 syntax in the same config

Comment: I use one at a time, still error

Comment: Not in option 2 you dont. Use either `Order allow,deny Allow from all` (Apache 2.2 syntax) OR `Require all granted` (Apache 2.4 syntax)

Comment: Tried both separatelly still same error. Updated question.

Answer (score 26):

I just fixed it !
Please go to :

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

and change all the contents as below:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
     AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
     Order allow,deny
     Require all granted
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: It seems the secret is removing "ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var"

Comment: Note there is no actual directory named phpMyAdmin - the line `Alias /phpmyadmin "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin"` in the conf file maps the /phpmyadmin path in the url to this "<Directory>"

Answer (score 26):

If you using Mac,
Go to Xampp Panel > Volumes > Mount, and here you are

[image]

then,

1. open httpd-xampp.conf
2. change:

> ```
> <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
>     Require local
>     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
> </Directory>
> ```

to:

> ```
> <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

5) Restart Services

Comment: Guys I have the same problem. I do all the steps above, but I don't have success.
I use a Mac (Catalina 10.15.5). 
If anyone has an idea how I can handle this problem, I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 8):

Nothing worked for me but following thing was awesome:

**1)** Open

> /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

**2)** Find `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">`

**3)** Now just add Require all granted before

**4)** So the code will look like this

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**5)** Now finally Restart XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

just comment this line "Require local"

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    #Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```